# Replacing elements of a dataframe using a corresponding dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to Map/Replace the elements of one dataframe with the element of another that corresponds. Let me give a an example.

I have this dataframe:

```
rbind(c("a","b","c"),c("b","a","c"),c("c","b","a"))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "b"  "c" 
[2,] "b"  "a"  "c" 
[3,] "c"  "b"  "a"
```

And this one:

```
   rbind(c("a",1),c("b",2),c("c",3))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "1" 
[2,] "b"  "2" 
[3,] "c"  "3"
```

How can I that replaces all the a's with 1s, all the b's with 2s, and all the c's with 3s. To get a final data frame that looks like this.

```
1   2   3
2   1   3
3   2   1
```

also, understand that I am doing this with a much larger data set. I just can't seem to find the right way to do this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post code that creates these objects.

Comment: df<-rbind(c("a","b","c"),c("b","a","c"),c("c","b","a"))

df1<-rbind(c("a",1),c("b",2),c("c",3))

Comment: For the given data, it could be `m1[] <- m2[,2][match(m1, m2[,1])]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would make more sense to create a named vector. Then you can use the indexing capabilities of the "[" function:

```
  a <- rbind(c("a","b","c"),c("b","a","c"),c("c","b","a"))
  b <- c("a"=1,"b"=2, "c"=3)

> b
a b c 
1 2 3 
> a[] <- b[a]
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "1"  "2"  "3" 
[2,] "2"  "1"  "3" 
[3,] "3"  "2"  "1"
```

Comment: That worked! Thank You very much. I really need to get more familiar with the "[" function.

Comment: Exactly. The "[" and "[[" functions are the core of R.

Answer (score 0):

Less elegant answer, but this can be done with reshaping.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

key = 
  rbind(c("a",1),c("b",2),c("c",3)) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  setNames(c("letter", "number"))

rbind(c("a","b","c"),c("b","a","c"),c("c","b","a")) %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  gather(variable, letter, -ID) %>%
  left_join(key) %>%
  select(-letter) %>%
  spread(variable, number)
```